# Mongodb create table from nested collection

Tags: mongodb

I'm using MongoDb 3.4, and i've about 400.000.000 records to rearrange. 
How can i transform documents like this :

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5a29777dce2ac011041718e9"),
    "elements": [{
            "IdSensore": "14348",
            "Valore": -2.5,
            "idOperatore": "1"
        }, {
            "IdSensore": "14351",
            "Valore": 16,
            "idOperatore": "1"
        }, {
            "IdSensore": "14355",
            "Valore": 10,
            "idOperatore": "1"
        }, {
            "IdSensore": "14355",
            "Valore": 356,
            "idOperatore": "3"
        }
    ],
    "Data": "01/01/2013 00:10:00"
}
```

in a table with Data value in rows and only specific IdSensore in multiple fields (some null) mathching idOperatore:1 ?
This is the desired result to export to another collection:

```
Data                    IdSensore:14348 IdSensore:14351 IdSensore:14355
01/01/2013 00:10:00         -2.5            16              10
```

In other words, in every row, i'd like to find all "Valore" for specified "IdSensore" and "idOperatore:1" in this sample.

Comment: Please don't add solved in title, instead accept the answer if it works for you or pass the solution that is working for you to learn more see [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
 db.startCollection.find().forEach(
 function(item){
     var data1 = item.Data;
     var finishObject  = {};
     finishObject["Data"] = data1;
     item.elements.filter(function(item2){return item2.idOperatore==1})
     .forEach(
            function(item2){
                    finishObject["IdSensore:"+item2.IdSensore] = item2.Valore;
            }
     );
     db.finishCollection2.insert(finishObject);
 })
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but it not runs due to some problem. I've rewrite yor suggestion to pair parentesis... but keep on give back SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):8:18.

Comment: Great ! thank you very much. Your solution takes 5 minutes for 239639 records (i7 with 12Gb RAM and SSD). I'll try with the other 400.000.000 records, perhaps i'll use bulk execution.

Comment: Do you have indexes in your db on this collections?

Comment: Also check your disk free.
In ubuntu/debian  df -h